# Displaying a blob in a template - Convert binary data into an image in a template

Tags: django, sqlite, django-templates

I am currently using sqlite as my database . Now one of my table contains a blob data which is basically an image.Due to certain reasons I am not using Djangos ORM and directly reading and writing from my database.Now I wanted to know how I can convert/render this binary data into an image in my template ?

Currently do display images I would do something like this

```
<img src=“pic.gif" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;">
```

But in this case the images are being constructed at run time and the data of the image is being passed from a view to the template.

The way i am storing images in db is something like this

```
def insert_Sample_imageInDB():
    picture_file="pic.jpg"
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    with open(picture_file, 'rb') as input_file:
        ablob = input_file.read()
        base = os.path.basename(picture_file)
        afile, ext = os.path.splitext(base)
        sql = "INSERT INTO ImageTable (image_col) VALUES(%s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, [sqlite3.Binary(ablob)])
        cursor.close()
```

Comment: is it a base64 array of data?

Comment: @Sayse I am not sure. However the way I am inserting the strings into the db is shown above. I am using python 3 and the default encoding is a byte which in python 2 was string.

Comment: ok, well as you've written it you won't be able to since you have the *files* binary data and not the images, you'll need to open the file stream and retrieve a base64 array for the *image*, in which case it is pretty straight forward how to load a base64 image in an img html tag

Comment: So are you suggesting converting the binary data to base64 ? and then displaying the image ?

Comment: I'm saying you load the binary data to open the image and then convert the image to base64, I'm pretty sure PIL makes this slighly easier but I've always done it raw (the conversion to base64)

Comment: I have never used PIL so I guess ill have to integrate that in my django project but i rather do it manually. Dont want to add a new library just for one feature

Comment: You can do it with native python methods but its slightly harder since you need to understand streams more. It will be much simpler if you're able to store base64 image data rather than the file binary

Comment: ok ill try to store base64 . Will that still be a blob column inside the database ?

Comment: I've always just used a `CharField`

Comment: ok will give that a try and post back

Comment: dont' save images as blobs

Comment: Yep I saved that as base64 and it works thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I basically stored the image in my database as a base64 encode string then displayed that image in my view using the following

```
 <img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ rslt }}" style="width:50px;height:50px;"/>
```